# Best Practice for Domain Entity Tracking Data? Base class or Composition?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, domain-driven-design, composition

One common aspect of most large projects is the need for common tracking data on many Domain Entities.  For instance, most large projects, track the following properties for many Domain Entities:

```
DateTime DateCreated
User CreatedBy
DateTime LastModified
User LastModifiedBy
```

This data is pretty self explanatory, the data is used to track who did what when to a Domain object.

The question is what's the best way to handle this tracking data when designing the domain model for a large application.

The classic way is to use a base class and then have the relevant domain classes inherit from that base class.  But this sets off my **[favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)** alarm bell.  The more large projects I've worked on, the more I reject inheritance out-of-hand, but that's not to say there are situations where it is the best option, perhaps in this case, for instance.  An alternate inheritance solution would be to use an **interface**, but while this solution is less coupled, I don't see many examples using this approach on domain entities.

The second way would be to use **composition** to add a tracking object of sorts to each domain entity.  The only problem with this is that the data-layer would have to be specifically instructed to not represent these as a separate table.  A minor task, but one that is hard to justify if there is no pay-off.

The final way to handle tracking data is to configure the data-layer to do this transparently.  I think it is probably possible to do this with **Entity-Framework**, but not having implemented this solution in the past, this would be the most upfront time intensive solution.  It is difficult to foresee if this solution would be worth the trouble.

While this question may seem objective, this is actually a common task that most large projects have to deal with one way or another.

What is the best way to design a domain model and/or a large project for tracking metadata?

Comment: For composition you can add a complex type which would map to the columns in the same table (i.e. not a separate table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is often subjective and can cause as many problems as it solves. When should you inherit? When should you compose? Scholars spend years arguing the toss over the minutiae of a problem. Basic inheritance with a simple interface is pragmatic and effective. If it's a standard feature for **all** your entities then inheritance is probably the better option.

I have a base class with the audit properties and implemented an interface for these properties. I intercept the call to the `context.SaveChanges()` with the following code. It's simple and it works. It could be extended to fail if any tracked entity does not implement the `IAudit` interface.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entities = this.GetChangedAuditDataEntities();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            this.SetModificationInfo(entity);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private IEnumerable<IAuditData> GetChangedAuditDataEntities()
    {
        return (
            from entry in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            where entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged
            select entry.Entity)
            .OfType<IAuditData>();
    }

    private void SetModificationInfo(IAuditData entity)
    {
        entity.lastModifiedBy = _currentUser.Name;
        entity.lastModified = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
```

---

This is one of those questions that does not automatically have a "correct" answer. If Jon Skeet were to answer it then it would be considered best practice. The only other correct answer will have to confirm your particular bias or at the every least strike the right intellectual note.

Years ago inheritance was rife and one of the many push backs from this has been the "value composition over inheritance" mantra. Fine, but inheritance has it's place.

I would suggest that any architectural layer that has many of the same type of object, such as a domain object (the words "domain object" imply common layer) can be greatly enhanced by having a common base class. `System.Object` is a good example of it. I'll give you another example. When we were defining the exception decorators for our solution we decided to extend the ToString() method to create a value that would uniquely identify the object.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this is IAuditData)
    {
        IAuditDataidentifiable = this as IAuditData;
        return string.Format(@"{0} {{ id: {1}, ETag: {2} }}",
            identifiable.GetType().Name,
            identifiable.id,
            identifiable.ETag);
    }
    else return base.ToString();
}
```

7 lines of code - pragmatic, simple and effective. From your question you sound wholly opposed to inheritance which must be borne from many a burnt finger. Me too ;-) but I still assert it's the better option in this instance.

Comment: While I take a different view of best practices, I can see your point that they can lead to quandaries.  However, would you still use a base class if **most**, but not **all** domain entities required this tracking data?

Comment: Yes, but I would only inherit for those classes that require audit data.

Comment: Do you use a base class (entity) for all your entities? This will make your queries really slow cause it will join all tables of the inheritance tree

Comment: We create the classes/maps/database with custom T4 templates so there is only one table for each entity. The inheritance is only in the object layer.

Answer (score 0):

I like what qujck has said in his answer and his comment but i would like to add something, if the tracking information represent an infrastructural concept i would go and put them in some infrastructure layer responsible for auditing or logging or etc .., otherwise if they are domain concepts i really like to keep them were they belong in the domain model layer and in this case i would use a complex object (value object) to represent them and to relief my self of the burden of setting them manually whenever i create a tracked object i would define a method that is called by my factory or IoC container whenever a tracked object is requested, my point is centralize change and keep concepts where they belong.

Comment: I agree with the factory/IoC point but Entity Framework does not support using your own container. It's possible to catch the underlying ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized event but I prefer to let the IoC container inject a decorator class to manage the audit logging - I have a UnitOfWork class that calls context.SubmitChanges and a decorator for the UnitOfWork that manages the audit logging.